# Angular ui Router views not working

Tags: angularjs, view, router

My code for the ui router is not working if I set the partial page a view and a name. please see code below.

html: I am using a tab as a parent state.

```
 <ul class="sidebar-nav">
               <li>
            <a ui-sref=".timeline" name="timeline-tab"><div class="chap-title">chap1</div></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a ui-sref=".chap2" name="chap2-tab"><div class="chap-title">chap2</div></a>
        </li>
  </ul>
<div ui-view></div>
```

and then the angular ui router:

```
//chap1 page
      .state('tab.timeline', {
        url: '/timeline',
            templateUrl: 'partials/chap1_timeline.html',
            controller: 'timelineController'
      })

//chapter 2
     .state('tab.chap2', {
        url:'/chap2',
        views:{
          'chap2-tab':{
            templateUrl:'partials/chap2_scroll.html',
            controller:'Chap2Controller'
          }
        }
      })
```

the router for chap1 works perfectly. but it's not working for chap2 when I add the view. I dont know what have I missing according to the tutorial

the problem for chap2 is that the whole page content/controller is not loading. no error msg, just no content

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using name instead of "state"?

Change the code as below and see if it works.

```
      //chap1 page
      .state('tab.timeline', {
        url: '/timeline',
            templateUrl: 'partials/chap1_timeline.html',
            controller: 'timelineController'
      })

    //chapter 2
         .state('tab.chap2', {
            url:'/chap2',
            views:{
              '.chap2':{
                templateUrl:'partials/chap2_scroll.html',
                controller:'Chap2Controller'
              }
            }
          })
```

Comment: The method you suggested works for me in the first place. it's because I was following a tutorial that uses the views{ 'name' { }} method. I want to figure out what what is wrong in that case for later more complex development from the tutorial

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/39KAoC
i have a very big file. this is the code involving the routing. but it's not working. I will try to minimize the files to something workable, but I never had any luck uploading large files onto plunker :(

Comment: try the above edited code once.. seems an issue in views. jus paste this thing and see if it is working

Comment: Hi vkrishna. thanks a lot for the help. after a while I figured out that it has something to do with the ionic framework. I did not using ionic but the tut included it.